# multiple functions on one argument with map

Tags: function, haskell

Is it possible to code a simple map function which allows to have multiple functions on one argument?
for example **mapmultiple [square, pred] 4 --> [16, 3]**

```
map1 :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map1 f [] = []
map1 f (x:xs) = foldr (\y ys -> (f y):ys) [] xs
```

map1 allows it with one function but how will it work out with two or three functions?

Comment: Hint: what would the type signature for `mapmultiple` be?

Comment: @Koterpillar the type should be `mapmultiple :: [a -> b] -> a -> [b]?`

Comment: Rather `[a -> b] -> [a] -> [[b]]` since you want to map over an array of values.

Comment: @DieterBrow yes, unless you want to apply multiple functions to multiple values, in which case see mschmidt's comment.

Comment: `mapmultiple = sequence`

Comment: @Koterpillar but how can I arrange this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just `map` with the arguments flipped.

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
mapmultiple :: [a -> b] -> a -> [b]
```

The "function" of `map` is going to be a higher-order function applying an argument.

```
mapmultiple fs x = map ($ x) fs
```

If you're not comfortable with the `$` section, this is equivalent<sup>[1]</sup> to

```
mapmultiple fs x = map (\f -> f x) fs
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> For a time, there was a GHC bug where sections would compile incorrectly to similar (but not quite equivalent) code. I'm uncertain as to whether it's been fixed. It shouldn't be relevant here, but I figure I should mention it.

Comment: It's not so much flipping the arguments as shifting the functor. With `f ~ []`, you are going from `(a -> b) -> f a -> f b` to `f (a -> b) -> a -> f b`.

Comment: I've never seen `($ x)` called a "slice".  The term I know is "section".

Comment: Hm... can't imagine where I got the term "slice" from, but you're right.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative with `sequence`

```
> mmap = map . sequence
> mmap [(^2), pred] [1..3]
[[1,0],[4,1],[9,2]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider a list comprehension:

```
map' fs x = [ f x | f <- fs ]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't committed to those exact arguments or order of arguments, two options are

```
>>> [(^ 2), pred] <*> pure 4
[16, 3]

>>> fmap ($ 4) [(^ 2), pred]
[16, 3]
```